# How to bundle images with Webpack?

Tags: image, webpack

I'm following webpack2 guide [asset managing](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/), all is well, but when I added my image it comes as a separate file next to bundle.js inside the dist folder, and because no reference in the index.html to that image it throws an error file not found.

I was thinking that the image will be handled inside the bundle.js.

So, I wish to discover how I can use images with webpack.

Here is my folder structure:

```
    dist
        bundel.js
        4942b81d7881a9d50c8984802eed28be.png
    node_modues
    src
        css
            style.css
        js
            app.js
            content.js
        images
            icon.png
    index.html
    package.json
    webpack.config.js
```

My app.js:

```
    const content = require("./content.js");
    import _ from 'lodash';
    import '../css/style.css'
    import icon from '../images/icon.png';

    document.write(content);
    console.log('Hello world!');

    /* Lodash */
    function component() {
        var element = document.createElement('div');

        element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');
        element.classList.add('hello');

        var myIMG = new Image();
        myIMG.src = icon;
        element.appendChild(myIMG);

        return element;
    }

    document.body.appendChild(component());
```

style.js:

```
    body {
        background: #bada55;
    }

     .hello {
        color: red;
        background: url('../images/icon.png');
      }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        entry: "./src/js/app.js",

        output: {
          filename: 'bundle.js',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
                    use: [
                        'file-loader'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }


    };
```

package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "letsLearnES6",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
        "webpack": "^3.6.0"
      }
    }
```

The error:

```
GET file:///...Root_directory_path.../4942b81d7881a9d50c8984802eed28be.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

That's because the image has been moved by webpack to:

```
file:///...Root_directory_path.../dist/4942b81d7881a9d50c8984802eed28be.png
```

What am I doing wrong and different from the [Webpack guide page](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/)?

Comment: What path of your image is placed into the bundle.js file?

Comment: please see my update at the end of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your index.html file inside dist directory because the file paths are generated relative to the output directory.

Also, you can use [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to dynamically generate your `index.html` file, because it is recommended to use hash in the assets file names to avoid the browser caching problems.

Comment: I tried moving the index.html ==> same error in the console

Comment: Also, using the  HTML Webpack Plugin will not solve the issue as the reference for the image in the eroor is at the root directory not the dist folder

Comment: You are right, the index.html should be inside the dist folder, my bad.. sorry i'm coming from gulp background :( ,   thank you